# XML parse error trying to deploy my web app in Tomcat

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, server

I've been trying to deploy my web application but I'm stuck trying to connect the app to a MySQL database. Here is the error in the log

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///opt/tomcat/webapps/server-pulsar/META-INF/context.xml; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 55; The reference to entity "k-4VePtY" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

and this is the context.xml file:

```
<Context>   
    <Resource name="jdbc/pulsar_consciente" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                   maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
                   username="migue" password="[mypass]" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pulsar_consciente?serverTimezone=UTC"/> 
</Context>
```

Can you help me? I'm driving nuts right now!
Thank you!

Comment: I’d say you’re looking at the wrong file — that doesn’t have 29 lines.

Comment: I removed a comment. It's definitely this file

Comment: It would be useful if you could give an error message which matches the file.

Comment: Is `k-4VePtY` a substring of your password?